# Dynamically change pdf export of report name in Cognos 10.2.1

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a report called "Sales". This report is run once a month by a scheduled job and sent by email in PDF format. My users want to have the month of the data to be shown in the filename, for example "Sales_201901" for the January execution "Sales_201902" for february and so on.

I've looked all over to see how can I do that and so far I've seen no option to do that. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance